# neo4j - win xp - delete database

Tags: neo4j

How can i completely delete the database of `neo4j` in `windows` (xp)?

First i installed the Movie-database of `neo4j` in my `opera-browser`. Everything was ok. The first node had the node id 0.

Then i deleted everything with: `START n=node(*) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() delete n,r;`

Finally i installed the Movie-database of neo4j again. But the first node didn´t have node id 0. Now the first node had the id 171.

But i would like to have an node id 0 again for my first node. What can i do?? I don´t want to reinstall `neo4j`.

Answer (score 1):

Stop your database, recursively delete `data/graph.db` directory, start Neo4j again. This completely wipes out the graph.

Comment: Windows can´t find a file graph.db

Comment: If you used the installer/starter it is the directory that you pointed Neo4j to at startup.